# Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT sprite kit

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to spawn multiple nodes in the x direction and then spawn them in the y direction as a unit. I spawned nodes in the x direction. I made a parent node that contains the nodes moving in x direction and tried to move the parent node in the y. I keeping getting "Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT" in AppDelegate.  Is this the correct approach?

Here's what I have so far:

```
     func addCloud() {
    var i = arc4random_uniform(2)
  // RandomCloud
    Cloud = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cloud\(i)")

    // Position
     Cloud.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width/3.5, height: self.size.height/12)
    Cloud.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*0.1 , self.frame.size.height*0.65)

    var radius = CGFloat(Cloud.size.width/2)
    Cloud.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
    Cloud.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Cloud
    Cloud.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.character
    Cloud.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.character
    Cloud.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Cloud.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
     Cloud.zPosition = 4
     allCloud.addChild(Cloud)
    Cloud.runAction(move) }

    func add1(){
    var i = arc4random_uniform(2)
    Cloud1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cloud\(i)")
    Cloud1.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*0.5 , self.frame.size.height*0.65)
    Cloud1.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width/3.5, height: self.size.height/12)
   Cloud1.zPosition = 4
    var radius = CGFloat(Cloud1.size.width/2)
    Cloud1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
    Cloud1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Cloud
    Cloud1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.character
    Cloud1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.character
    Cloud1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Cloud1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
     allCloud.addChild(Cloud1)
    Cloud1.runAction(move1)}
     func add2(){
    var i = arc4random_uniform(2)
    Cloud2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cloud\(i)")
    Cloud2.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*0.9 , self.frame.size.height*0.65)
    Cloud2.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width/3.5, height: self.size.height/12)
    Cloud2.zPosition = 4
    var radius = CGFloat(Cloud2.size.width/2)
    Cloud2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
    Cloud2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Cloud
    Cloud2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.character
    Cloud2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.character
    Cloud2.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Cloud2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
     allCloud.addChild(Cloud2)
    Cloud2.runAction(move2)


}

func add3() {
    var i = arc4random_uniform(2)
    Cloud3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cloud\(i)")
    Cloud3.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + Cloud3.size.width/2 , self.frame.size.height*0.65)
    Cloud3.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width/3.5, height: self.size.height/12)
    Cloud3.zPosition = 4
    var radius = CGFloat(Cloud3.size.width/2)
    Cloud3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
    Cloud3.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Cloud
    Cloud3.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.character
    Cloud3.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.character
    Cloud3.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Cloud3.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    allCloud.addChild(Cloud3)
    Cloud3.runAction(move3)


}
func add4() {
    var i = arc4random_uniform(2)
    Cloud4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cloud\(i)")
    Cloud4.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + Cloud4.size.width/2 , self.frame.size.height*0.65)
    Cloud4.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width/3.5, height: self.size.height/12)
   Cloud4.zPosition = 4
    var radius = CGFloat(Cloud4.size.width/2)
    Cloud4.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
    Cloud4.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Cloud
    Cloud4.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.character
    Cloud4.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.character
    Cloud4.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Cloud4.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    allCloud.addChild(Cloud4)

    Cloud4.runAction(move4)


}
func add5() {
    var i = arc4random_uniform(2)
    Cloud5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cloud\(i)")
    Cloud5.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + Cloud5.size.width/2 , self.frame.size.height*0.65)
   Cloud5.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width/3.5, height: self.size.height/12)
    Cloud5.zPosition = 4
    var radius = CGFloat(Cloud5.size.width/2)
    Cloud5.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
    Cloud5.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Cloud
    Cloud5.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.character
    Cloud5.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.character
    Cloud5.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Cloud5.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    allCloud.addChild(Cloud5)
    Cloud5.runAction(move5)

}

func add6() {
    var i = arc4random_uniform(2)
   Cloud6 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cloud\(i)")
    Cloud6.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + Cloud6.size.width/2 , self.frame.size.height*0.65)
    Cloud6.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width/3.5, height: self.size.height/12)
    Cloud6.zPosition = 4
    var radius = CGFloat(Cloud6.size.width/2)
    Cloud6.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
    Cloud6.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Cloud
    Cloud6.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.character
    Cloud6.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.character
    Cloud6.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Cloud6.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Cloud6.runAction(move6)
     allCloud.addChild(Cloud6)
}

func addall (){

self.addChild(allCloud)
    allCloud.runAction(move7)
}
func spawnCloudX() {


    var remove = SKAction.runBlock({self.allCloud.removeFromParent()})



    var distance = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + Cloud.size.width/2)
    var distance1 = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + Cloud1.size.width/2)
     var distance2 = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + Cloud2.size.width/2)
     var distance3 = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + Cloud3.size.width/2)
     var distance4 = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + Cloud4.size.width/2)
     var distance5 = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + Cloud5.size.width/2)
     var distance6 = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + Cloud6.size.width/2)



    var add:SKAction = SKAction.runBlock({
        () in
        self.addCloud()})
    var add1:SKAction = SKAction.runBlock({
        () in
        self.add1()})
    var add2:SKAction = SKAction.runBlock({
        () in
        self.add2()})
    var add3:SKAction = SKAction.runBlock({
        () in
        self.add3()})
    var add4:SKAction = SKAction.runBlock({
        () in
        self.add4()})
    var add5:SKAction = SKAction.runBlock({
        () in
        self.add5()})
    var add6:SKAction = SKAction.runBlock({
        () in
        self.add6})

    var removea = SKAction.removeFromParent()


    var movex = SKAction.moveToX(-distance, duration: 5)
    var movex1 = SKAction.moveToX(-distance1, duration: 6.5)
    var movex2 = SKAction.moveToX(-distance2, duration: 8)
    var movex3 = SKAction.moveToX(-distance3, duration: 10)
    var movex4 = SKAction.moveToX(-distance4, duration: 10)
    var movex5 = SKAction.moveToX(-distance5, duration: 10)
    var movex6 = SKAction.moveToX(-distance6, duration: 10)



    var delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(2)
   var spawn = SKAction.sequence([add3,delay,add4,delay,add5,delay,add6])
    self.runAction(add)
    self.runAction(add1)
    self.runAction(add2)
    var spawnforever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawn)
    self.runAction(spawnforever)


    move = SKAction.sequence([movex,removea])
    move1 = SKAction.sequence([movex1,removea])
    move2 = SKAction.sequence([movex2,removea])
    move3 = SKAction.sequence([movex3,removea])
    move4 = SKAction.sequence([movex4,removea])
    move5 = SKAction.sequence([movex5,removea])
    move6 = SKAction.sequence([movex6,removea])

            var distance7 = CGFloat(self.frame.size.height + allCloud.size.height/2)
    var movey7 = SKAction.moveToY(distance7, duration: 5)

    var addall: SKAction = SKAction.runBlock({
        () in
        self.addall() })
    var delayY = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
    var spawnY = SKAction.sequence([addall,delayY])
    var spawnYforever = SKAction.repeatAction(spawnY, count: 2)
    move7 = SKAction.sequence([movey7,removea])

    self.runAction(spawnYforever)


}
```

Sorry for the long code.
Thank you,

Comment: I've looked at your code for an hour and can still not figure out what the heck the purpose of this is. I've cleaned your code form 200+ lines to 70 lines and still have too many redundancies. please just explain in plain english what you want to happen on the screen

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. My goal is to create separate nodes that move in the x axis at a certain rate. Then move those nodes in y axis together at a certain rate. Hence spawning in the x axis separately and in the y axis as a unit. I wanna it to look like the clouds are moving left and moving up. I hope this makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: this code is waaaaaay to incredibly complex for what you trying to achieve, it is massive overkill.

Comment: do the clouds need to be physics bodies?

Comment: why are you removing the clouds after the x move if you want them to move upwards?

Comment: Because once they move off the view they become irrelevant and I dont wanna have too many nodes.

Comment: I'll take your advise and try to find an easier way. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: you're missing the point, I am trying to help you not get you to scrap this. You need to explain clearly what outcome you expect. how can they go off the screen if you expect them to move up?

Comment: Think of the clouds moving in x axis as a moving treadmill belt. Now move the clouds across the screen vertically. I expect them to move horizontally and vertically at once. They will go off the screen while moving up because they are also move side ways.

Answer (score 0):

try this code and see if it works for you.

```
spawnClouds()

func createCloud() -> SKSpriteNode {

    let i = arc4random_uniform(2) + 1
    let randomPos = arc4random_uniform(200)

    let cloud = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cloud\(i)")
    cloud.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width + cloud.size.width / 2 - CGFloat(50 + randomPos) , self.size.height * 0.65 - CGFloat(50 + randomPos))
    cloud.zPosition = 4000
    let radius = CGFloat(cloud.size.width / 2)
    cloud.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
    cloud.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Cloud
    cloud.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Hero
    cloud.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Hero
    cloud.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    cloud.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    addChild(cloud)

    return cloud
}

func spawnClouds() {

    for _ in 0..<5 {

        let addAndMoveCloud = SKAction.runBlock({
            let randomDuration = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(2)) / 5 + 10
            let cloud = self.createCloud()
            cloud.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: -cloud.size.width, y: self.size.height + cloud.size.height), duration: NSTimeInterval(randomDuration)), completion: { cloud.removeFromParent()
            })
        })

        let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(2)
        let spawnClouds = SKAction.sequence([addAndMoveCloud, delay])

        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnClouds))
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is the clouds move up individually. Thats why I made a parent node  so children nodes can move together.

Comment: Btw my code works perfectly when I call repeat action once (Count = 1).

Comment: 200+ lines of code to move some clouds across the screen "perfectly" is subjective. I've changed the code to make a group of clouds

Comment: the clouds are moving at an angle. Remember the treadmill belt analogy, its not looking like that.

Comment: Hey! I have a new question, can you please help me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601845/slow-skscene-transition here's the link. Thanks !